# How can I store images in an array in octave?

Tags: arrays, image, matrix, octave

I have an read image got with the imread function.
Now, I need to create a random number of images with noise, appling the noise function.
The main problem is: The amount of images will be random. so I tried to create a cell array and store the images in each position (array(1)=img1, array(2)=img2, and so on). But using it, the array(1) and so on doesn't let me work with my image.

So how can I really put all of them in a array and use them normaly?

Tank you!

Comment: I think your problem is that you've used array(1) instead array{1} to assign into the cell array. If this is not your problem show what you've tried so far, show some code...

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB and Octave have pretty much the same language.
Please try the following:

```
for i=1:length(images)
  array_of_images{i}=images(i);
end
```

I think it should work something similar or exactly this